# Runtime error in Linked List

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I have been working with Linked Lists (for learning purpose, using `class`). I decided to use `friend` function this time. The program generates 2 linked lists objects and calls the `friend void mergeAlternate(LL LL1, LL LL2);` function. (`LL` is the name of my class)

The `mergeAlternate` function takes nodes from both the linked list and places them alternatively.
For example:

LL1: 1->2->3

LL2: 4->5->6

Ans: 1->4->2->5->3->6

This is my code::

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node(int data) {
        this->data = data;
        this->next = NULL;
    }
};
class LL {
private:
    Node *head;
public:

    LL() : head(NULL) {
        createLL();
    }

    void printLL(Node *head) {
        if(head == NULL)
            head = this->head;
        Node *temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            cout << temp->data << "-->";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << "NULL" << endl;
    }

    void createLL() {
        head = new Node(2);
        head->next = new Node(7);
        head->next->next = new Node(8);
        head->next->next->next = new Node(1);
        head->next->next->next->next = new Node(4);
        head->next->next->next->next->next = new Node(9);
    }

    friend void mergeAlternate(LL LL1, LL LL2);

    ~LL() {
        Node *temp = NULL;
        while (head != NULL) {
            temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
};

void mergeAlternate(LL LL1, LL LL2) {
        Node *head1 = LL1.head, *head2 = LL2.head;
        Node *temp1, *temp2;
        while ((head1 != NULL) && (head2 != NULL)) {
            temp1 = head1->next;
            temp2 = head2->next;
            head1->next = head2;
            head2->next = temp1;
            if (temp1 == NULL)
                break;
            head1 = temp1;
            head2 = temp2;
        }
        if (head2 != NULL) {
            head1->next = head2;
        }
        LL2.head = NULL;
        LL1.printLL(LL1.head);
    }

int main() {
LL newLL, newLL2;
    newLL2.printLL(NULL);
    mergeAlternate(newLL, newLL2);
    newLL2.printLL(NULL);
}
```

I have a `printLL` function used to print the linked list.

The problem is that in my `mergeAlternate` I pass 2 Linked Lists by value. So, I expect the Linked list `newLL` and `newLL2` to remain the same. But, in the `main`, after the execution of the `mergeAlternate` when I print the Linked List, I get a runtime error, and something like this prints.

`155672576-->155672672-->155672592-->155672688-->155672608-->155672704-->155672624-->155672720-->155672640-->155672736-->155672656-->NULL`

Though I expect the same input Linked List to print again. Why does this happen?? Is there something that I am missing?? Thanks for any help :)

ideone link :: http://ideone.com/apRCTw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `void mergeAlternate(LL LL1, LL LL2)` creates two new local variables `LL` and `LL2` whose member `head` will also point to the same memory address that `newLL` and `newLL2` respectively points to. Because `LL1` and `LL2` are local variables of the function, when the function ends, their respective destructors will be called. According to your destructor definition:

```
~LL() {
    Node *temp = NULL;
    while (head != NULL) {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

It will de-allocate the `Nodes` of `LL1` and `LL2`, however because these are the same memory addresses as `newLL` and `newLL2` that means that when the function ends these last two objects will be having garbage values in their member `head` and subsequent references, which will cause errors when trying access their values.

Comment: They won't be NULL but they'll point to garbage hence the random values being printed. Still that's how the random values end up being printed.

Answer (score 3):

I see a few pitfalls in there.

You're passing your lists by value, including their internal pointers. This means that the lists that are created by copy within the function point to the same data structures as the original lists. So any changes you make inside the function will be "seen" in the original lists.

You did what would be called a "shallow copy" of the list. You didn't copy the contents of the list.

To solve this you need to make a deep copy of your lists. Either make a function that creates a copy of a list or create copies of the nodes as you iterate over them. The first solution is probably less error prone though.

Answer (score 2):

You pass `LL` by value, but since that class is only a wrapper around a pointer to your nodes you are actually passing two pointers to the heads of the respective lists.And since you're then modifying the nodes these pointers point to, which are the same nodes that the `LL` instances of the caller are using, you're effectively modifying the callers lists.Just think about how many different nodes there should be after calling your function:

```
LL1: 1->2->3
LL2: 4->5->6
Ans: 1->4->2->5->3->6
```

That's 2 times 3 nodes for LL1 and LL2 plus 6 for the answer, making a total of 12 nodes. When constructing LL1 and LL2 you allocated 6 nodes.

To solve this you need to make (allocate) copies of the nodes as you are merging the lists, modifying only these copies.